# How to add conditional fields to ModelAdmin in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have model classes:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    ...
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    properies = models.ManyToManyField(Property)
    ...
#property type, ex: 'weight', 'length'
class Property(models.Model):
    ...
#value for every product
class PropertyValue(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)
    ...
```

and I need custom product/add/ page, having PropertyValue forms set depends on chosen category.
I've made a method getting PropertyValue list by category_id in ModelAdmin class, but how can I call it in runtime when chosen category changes? Is it possible in django?

Comment: please do add the relevevnt sections of the admin class

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you said in runtime. If those categories change, the new records will apear every time you load the add pages.

Did you do yor form class? Kind of:

```
class PropertyValueForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all())
    property = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Property.objects.all())
```

Or:

```
def getProduct():
    # DO YOUR STUFF
    return product_list

class PropertyValueForm(forms.Form):
    product  = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_my_choices())
```